# How to add products with webservice into prestashop from and xml file

Tags: php, xml, prestashop

i have this xml file that is being generated by a stock management software i have that i would like to insert it into the Pretashop database. can anybody please help me with this xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
<Products>
<Reference>1101TEST</Reference>
<Valid_internet_product>1</Valid_internet_product>
<Products_name>universal</Products_name>
<Price>69.95</Price>
<Active_product>1</Active_product>
<SupplierNo>08</SupplierNo>
<Weight>5</Weight>
<Description>Koncentreret universalmiddel med salmiak</Description>
<Short_Description>Koncentreret universalmiddel med salmiak</Short_Description>
<MinOrderQty>1</MinOrderQty>
<Categories>
<Category>
<CategoryID>63</CategoryID>
<CategoryName>Bins\Universal</CategoryName>
<Active_category>1</Active_category>
<Changed>0</Changed>
</Category>
</Categories>
<Tax_Class_ID>1</Tax_Class_ID>
<Discount>
<Discount_percentage>percentage</Discount_percentage>
<discountprice_ex_vat>0</discountprice_ex_vat>
<Discountprice_include_vat>0</Discountprice_include_vat>
<Pct_ReductionPercent>0</Pct_ReductionPercent>
</Discount>
</Products>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 4):

With PrestaShop you can easily import your data using one of these options:

1. By using the "CSV Import" feature in your Back-office (assuming you also have a .csv export instead of this XML file)
2. By using the PrestaShop Web-service (custom development required)
3. By using the existing classes (custom development required)

Below is a quick code snippet that is working with your XML string.
It will create or update all the products, and take into account their price, availability, name, description, weight, etc.

Please note that:

- This code will is not designed to work with combinations (color, sizes, etc.)
- This code does not create categories for you, and is adding all the products to the "Home" category

This is just an example to assist you ;)

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/init.php');

$xml_string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
<Products>
<Reference>1101TEST</Reference>
<Valid_internet_product>1</Valid_internet_product>
<Products_name>universal</Products_name>
<Price>69.95</Price>
<Active_product>1</Active_product>
<SupplierNo>08</SupplierNo>
<Weight>5</Weight>
<Description>Koncentreret universalmiddel med salmiak</Description>
<Short_Description>Koncentreret universalmiddel med salmiak</Short_Description>
<MinOrderQty>1</MinOrderQty>
<Categories>
<Category>
<CategoryID>63</CategoryID>
<CategoryName>Bins\Universal</CategoryName>
<Active_category>1</Active_category>
<Changed>0</Changed>
</Category>
</Categories>
<Tax_Class_ID>1</Tax_Class_ID>
<Discount>
<Discount_percentage>percentage</Discount_percentage>
<discountprice_ex_vat>0</discountprice_ex_vat>
<Discountprice_include_vat>0</Discountprice_include_vat>
<Pct_ReductionPercent>0</Pct_ReductionPercent>
</Discount>
</Products>
</Document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach ($xml->Products as $product_xml)
{
    if ($product_xml->Valid_internet_product == 1)
    {
        /* Update an existing product or Create a new one */
        $id_product = (int)Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE reference = \''.pSQL($product_xml->Reference).'\'');
        $product = $id_product ? new Product((int)$id_product, true) : new Product();
        $product->reference = $product_xml->Reference;
        $product->price = (float)$product_xml->Price;
        $product->active = (int)$product_xml->Active_product;
        $product->weight = (float)$product_xml->Weight;
        $product->minimal_quantity = (int)$product_xml->MinOrderQty;
        $product->id_category_default = 2;
        $product->name[1] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Products_name);
        $product->description[1] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Description);
        $product->description_short[1] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Short_Description);
        $product->link_rewrite[1] = Tools::link_rewrite($product_xml->Products_name);
        if (!isset($product->date_add) || empty($product->date_add))
            $product->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $product->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id_product ? $product->updateCategories(array(2)) : $product->addToCategories(array(2));
        $product->save();

        echo 'Product <b>'.$product->name[1].'</b> '.($id_product ? 'updated' : 'created').'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Bruno, the loop throws an error as follows : "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopException' with message 'Property Product->link_rewrite is empty". Any clue ?